# Breakout Clone Lives Bug

Tags: javascript, if-statement, canvas, collision-detection

I am currently making a Breakout clone and it's almost fully playable, but I'm running into an issue with the ball: When the ball hits the bottom of the canvas, it should normally reset to its starting position, but in my case it just keeps bouncing towards the bottom again. Here's some of the collision code. You can see all of the code on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/uncledrew35/pen/RgwOON?).

```
else if(y + dy > canvas.height - ballRadius) {
    if(x > paddleX && x < paddleX + paddleWidth) {
        dy = -dy;
    }
    else {
        lives--;
        if(!lives) {
            alert("GAME OVER!");
            window.location.reload(true);
        }
        else {
            x = canvas.width / 2;
            y = canvas.height - 30;
            dx = 2;
            dx = -2;
        }
   }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in the code that resets the position and direction of the ball. Should be:

```
{
    x = canvas.width / 2;
    y = canvas.height - 30;
    dx = 2;
    dy = -2;
}
```